# How do I clone a running VMware Workstation?

Tags: backup, vmware-workstation, clone, snapshot

I have a running virtual machine with a task that cannot be turned off. I tried to snapshot it but unfortunately, it won't allow me to use a snapshot that is powered on to create a new cloning machine. It only allows me to use the one that is turned off.

I want several copies of this running machine with this program still running on other copies.

Any idea how to do this?  The machine can be suspended, but can not be shut down because the task will be closed too.

Or is there a way to keep the program running even shutting down the window?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. If you can suspend it, you can copy the files and resume the vm on a different machine. You'd need to ensure the machines do not see each other and that you resume it on the same hardware.

Comment: Do you mean a different physical machine? Like another laptop or computer?

Comment: If it was top be the same machine, you'd need to manually change identifiers in .vmx configuration file.

Comment: Thank you, where is the configuration file located anyway?

Comment: By default in the same directory as the whole virtual machine.

Comment: Just remember that if you run the same machine and do not isolate it from the current one some conflict could occur and your application might fall.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, I'm new to VMware Workstation. The one that I want to make a clone that has an application running on it is a linked clone named A2, the base virtual machine is A1. So do I have to reconfigure the file in This PC/Documents/Virtual Machines/A2 or PC/Documents/Virtual Machines/A1? Thanks again.

Comment: If you have linked clones, you'd better set it up on a separate physical machine (and copy all machines intact). You can use VMware Player instead of Workstation.

Comment: I've successfully resumed all copies of these running machine. It works but the problem is all copies has no internet connection, but the original linked clone has and they all have same mac address. How do I fix this?

Comment: I've got everything done and running fine, thankyou sir!!!